# Linux script formating multiline into 1 line

Tags: linux, bash

I have created a linux bash script to loop through all of my servers and display the hostname and password expiration date of a specified account (inputed by the user).  my problem is that I can't get it to display on one line.  it works fine, just displays hostname on line 1, then account info on line 2 and I would like them both on one line.

code:

```
echo "Enter the account name you want to check: "

read act

echo "you entered: $act - searching for account information"

cat /home/admin/me/linuxhosts | xargs -i ssh {} 'hostname; chage -l '$act' | grep "Password expires";'
```

any formatting help to get the hostname and chage info to display on one line would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the command substitution "$()".  It will eat the newline.

```
echo "Enter the account name you want to check: "

read act

echo "you entered: $act - searching for account information"

cat /home/admin/me/linuxhosts | xargs -i ssh {} 'echo $(hostname; chage -l '$act' | grep "Password expires");'
```

Comment: thats exactly what i was looking for, i tried it before but apparently had the () in the wrong place and assumed it wasn't a valid solution... Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Unless your implementation is strange:

```
grep "Password expires"
```

should be

```
grep "Password Expires"
```

If the difficulty is having the correct line returned, that will solve it:

```
sudo chage $user -l | grep "Password Expires"
```

output:

```
Password Expires:       Never
```

As in the other answer, enclosing in either `$(...)` or `backticks` will suppress, but not eliminate, newlines

Comment: it really is Password expires, lower case e /shrug.  i checked the results of the chage -l command and then greped just for the password expires and it is lower case e.

Comment: Wow, surprising it differs from implementation to implementation. Sorry for the confusion.